# How can I replicate a CouchDB database?

Tags: couchdb

I would like to replicate the CouchDB database https://github.com/kirel/detexify-data

Sadly, I get an error:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"source":"https://kirelabs.cloudant.com/detexify","target":"detexify"}' http://localhost:5984/_replicate
{"error":"checkpoint_commit_failure","reason":"Failure on source commit: {error,<<\"unauthorized\">>}"}
```

This seems to be the following error: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1524

Can anybody please tell me if there is a work-around? How can I get the data?

### Failed tries

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -d '{"source":"https://kirelabs.cloudant.com/detexify",
       "target":"detexify",
       "use_checkpoints":false}'
  http://localhost:5984/_replicate

{"error":"checkpoint_commit_failure",
 "reason":"Failure on source commit: {error,<<\"unauthorized\">>}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a quick easy solution is to not use checkpoints.

`{"source":"https://kirelabs.cloudant.com/detexify","target":"detexify","use_checkpoints":false}`

I tried it with this request and managed to replicate your data.

**Update**

Well I tried it again and replication seems to be working fine for me. I replicated 22.7 mb of data before cancelling the replication. I have attached a screenshot.

[image: replication in progress]

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"   -d   '{"source":"https://kirelabs.cloudant.com/detexify",
   "target":"detexify",
   "use_checkpoints":false,"create_target":true}' http://ABBA:dancing-queen@localhost:5984/_replicate
```

The replication command was copied verbatim from your updated example except for the "create_target" option and admin basic authentication on my local database.